# Drupal Commerce Shopping Cart Form Alter

Tags: 7, forms, commerce

I'm trying to use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() in my theme's template.php file to change the 'Remove' button in the Commerce add to cart form to an image button. To do this I'm using the following code:

```
function tempestra_form_views_form_commerce_cart_form_default_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  foreach($form['edit_delete'] as $item) {
    if($item['#type'] == 'submit') {
      $item['#type'] = 'image_button';
      $item['#src'] = base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'tempestra') . '/images/search.png';
      unset($item['#name']);
      dpm($item);
    }
  }
}
```

When I look in the array printed by `dpm()` everything is as it should be, however the HTML for the image button isn't printed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple mistake, you don't change `$form` but only `$item` if you did

```
foreach($form['edit_delete'] as &$item) {
```

or

```
foreach($form['edit_delete'] as $key => $item) {
  ...
  $form['edit_delete'][$key] = $item;
}
```

it should work.

Comment: Yeah that now works perfectly, I hadn't thought about it that way or even realised you could use `&` in a foreach statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  if (strpos($form_id, 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form') !== FALSE) {
    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Buy now'),
    );
  }
}
```